# View/Property transition

Tags: android, animation, android-transitions

[image]
I have the following transition which I need to make when user scrolls the recyclerview down as shown in the image attached. The "Title A" and "Description" are inside a RelativeLayout and will collapse and their properties changed:

1. "Title A" from layout_centerHorizontal=true to layout_centerVertical=true
2. "Description" from layout_centerHorizontal=true to layout_centerVertical=true, textsize from 30sp to 16sp
3. Minimize the relativelayout, height from 70dp to wrap_content

When user scrolls up and hit the top, the changes will revert to original expanded form. (This is similar to the concept of collapsingtoolbar)

I've successfully implemented such that when i click on a button, the layout and views will change correctly using view.requestlayout(). But I'm not sure how to link the transitions to deltaY of onscrolled function.

Here is what I've tried:

```
    changeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            animateChanges();
        }
    });

 private void animateChanges() {

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layout = relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams header = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) titleA.getLayoutParams();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams value = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) description.getLayoutParams();

    // if current is not expanded, we change to expand view
    if (!isExpanded) {
        relativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height_60);
        header.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        header.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
        header.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0);
        value.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        value.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.title_a);
        value.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
        value.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            value.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, 0);
            header.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, 0);
        }
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layout);
        titleA.setLayoutParams(header);
        description.setLayoutParams(value);
        description.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_30));

        titleA.requestLayout();
        description.requestLayout();
        relativeLayout.requestLayout();
    } else {

        relativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        layout.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        header.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0);
        header.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 0);
        header.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        header.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        value.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0);
        value.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        value.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 0);
        value.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            value.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            header.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        }
        titleA.setLayoutParams(header);
        description.setLayoutParams(value);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layout);
        description.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_16));

        relativeLayout.requestLayout();
        titleA.requestLayout();
        description.requestLayout();
    }
    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
}
```

Thanks in advance!